# Shortcuts to copy bibtex and citation key in Zotero

Tags: mendeley

In Mendeley I can type ctrl+c to copy an article's bibtex entry, and ctrl+k to copy a latex cite command with that article's cite key.

How can I do the same in Zotero? I am running Better Bibtex.

Comment: In the newest version of Mendeley Ctrl + K is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First, make sure the Better BibTeX add-on works and is there to help you with the quick-copy:

Edit > Prefernences > BetterBibteX > Export > Quick-Copy (to configure):

[image: Quick-copy configuration]

Then, in Edit > Preferences > Export > Quick Copy / Item format, pick the right better-bibtex format for you in the dropdown menu:

[image: select_export_format_screenshot]

Then your `Ctrl + Shift + C` should copy the key no problem:

> \cite{fengDrugCombinationsBorrelia2015}

Comment: Can I configure this at the same time as having a shortcut to export the full bibtex entry? If so, what would the shortcut to export the bibtex entry be?